# How to pass an Array of objects from Redux store to component in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on a React project, In that I have an Array of objects in a store so someone please

Tell me how to pass an Array of objects from the Redux store to react component.

In my project I have App.js that is Parent for that Parent I have two Childs, one is Childone

Component another one is Childtwo Component.

Now I am trying to pass an Array of Objects from Redux store to Childtwo Component

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Childone from './Childone/Childone';
import Childtwo from './Childtwo/Childtwo';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Childone></Childone>
      <Childtwo></Childtwo>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is Datatypes.js

```
export const studentsTypesVariable = 'STUDENTS'
```

This is Dataactions.js

```
import { studentsTypesVariable } from './Datatypes';

export const studentsActionsVariable = () => {
    return {
        type: studentsTypesVariable
    }
}
```

This is Datareducer.js

```
import { studentsTypesVariable } from './Datatypes';

const initialState = {
    data: [{}]
}


const arrayOfStudents = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case studentsTypesVariable: return {
            ...state,
            data: state.data === 0 ? [{
                name: 'Tesla',
                age: 21
            },
            {
                name: "William",
                age: 24
            }] : state.data
        }
        default: return state
    }
}

export default arrayOfStudents
```

This is store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import  mainReducer  from './Data/Datareducer';


const store = createStore(mainReducer);

export default store
```

This is Chiltwo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './Childtwo.css';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';


import { studentsActionsVariable } from '../Redux/Data/Dataactions';

const Childtwo = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='bg-success'><h1>Two</h1>{props.Fun}</div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        data: state.data
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        Fun: () => dispatch(studentsActionsVariable())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Childtwo)
```

Comment: Code looks correct. You should get the array using `props.data` in component,

Comment: Hi @MurliPrajapati If I put props.data then it is showing error.

Comment: It is showing Error like this ---> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

`props.data` is an array so you must iterate through the array in order to render the items in it:

```js
// Childtwo.js

<div className='bg-success'>
  <h1>Two</h1>
  {props.data.map(item => <p>{item.name}</p>)}
</div>
```

The above code will work, however if you open the browser console you will notice that React logs a warning:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

In order for React to keep track of changes to an array each item in the array needs a unique identity. Usually this is achieved using an ID:

```js
{props.data.map(item => <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>)}
```

However if a unique identifier isn't available you can use the position of the item in the array (its index), although [this isn't recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

```js
{props.data.map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>)}
```

Attempting to render the array without iterating through it (i.e: `<p>{props.data}</p>`) throws the `Objects are not valid as a React child` error because in JavaScript arrays are objects:

```js
typeof ["an", "array"] // returns "object"`
```

Comment: Hi @Callum Hart  I tried our code it, I didn't see any change in output.

Comment: It sounds like `props.data` could be empty. Where are you dispatching the action that populates the array?